# htaccess causing 500 internal server error (.php & variables)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Here is my .htaccess file. I don't know what's going on, but trying to access any non-existing page throws a 500 Internal Server Error. I would like to fix this so I can add a custom 404 error page. Any help is appreciated.

```
Options -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteRule ^song/(.+)$ song.php?name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Look at the error logs of your webserver. There will be a detailed message what's wrong.

Comment: Error message I get with your .htaccess: "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.".

Comment: I have a ton of errors on the shared server. The ones I suspect are part of this are: RewriteCond: NoCase option for non-regex pattern '-f' is not supported and will be ignored. / the one Gerald mentioned above / and some random things like mod_rbl: [ip address] is listed in RBL. I do not know what any of this means.